# Dynamically Create table from JSON and perform operations on columns after table has been generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

i'm trying to create a dynamic table that gets JSON via an an Ajax call, create a table out of that data. I've this part done but my main issue is, one of the table columns will be an editable field that should a different column that was created via the ajax.

My main real issue is how to tell JQuery that I want the column next door to it to update.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.tabletojson.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </thead>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("objects.txt", function(response){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        $.each(obj.data, function(key,value){
            $("#example tbody").append("<tr>");
            $("#example tbody").append("<td contenteditable=true>"+ value.name +"</td>");
            $("#example tbody").append("<td>" + value.position +"</td>")
            $("#example tbody").append("<td>" + value.Office +"</td>")
            $("#example tbody").append("</tr>");
        });
        //uses a table to json library
        var json = $("#example").tableToJSON();
    });
});

</script>
</body>
```

For simplicities sake, When the field "name" is editted, I want the office field to be editted that is on that row. Not entirely sure where to go from here.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: The DOM is a *Document Object Model*, not a bunch of HTML text. There's no such thing as appending just an "open tag" or a "close tag". You deal with whole elements, which are objects. You can create these element objects from whole and complete HTML strings.

Comment: @rockstar Thank you for the reply, I guess I don't really have an understanding of what a DOM is. Back to the drawing board :)

Comment: Yep, things will make much more sense when you figure that out. But just think of a tree of objects. `document` at the top, under that the `HTML` element (referenced as `documentElement`), under that the `head` and `body` elements, under those, their respective children, and so on. So when you create a new element, you're creating an object, and placing as a new child of an existing element that is somewhere in that tree structure.

Comment: And html is just used to tell browser how to create those objects. But when you create objects yourself they ar complete elements

Answer (score 1):

Try combining the entire `<tr>` into one call to append.

```js
var obj = {
  data: [
    {
      name: "person 1",
      position: "President",
      Office: "Corner"
    },
    {
      name: "person 2",
      position: "Developer",
      Office: "Penthouse"
    },
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each(obj.data, function(key,value){
    $("#example tbody").append("<tr><td contenteditable=true>"+ value.name +"</td><td>" + value.position +"</td><td>" + value.Office +"</td></tr>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody></tbody>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer but the question was not about how to create a dynamically created table but to create e dyanmicly created table where one of the columns would be set to contenteditable. then when a user types in of the row cells in the editable cells, a value in a different column changes.

Comment: Look into the `change` event. With that you should be able to know when the content changes.